# Magento Error report message show in alert box in ajax response

Tags: ajax, magento, virtual, error-reporting

I am adding virtual products to cart by my custom ajax function and now virtual products can only be added one in the cart.if i had second one in the cart it is generating error report as Nominal items can only be purchased as standlone.

I want to show this message on the alert box on the add to cart button page which should i get in the ajax response data.

Thanks In Advance